# HTMLEntities and URLencode in Laravel link

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm creating my own password reset system on my Laravel app, and when I email the user the recovery link, shown here:

```
<a href='{{ url("forgotpassword/reset?email={$user->email}&recovery={$recoveryString}") }}'>click this link and reset your password!</a>
```

the ampersand becomes "&".

I tried doing things likes

```
{{ url("forgotpassword/reset?email={$user->email} }}<?php echo urlencode('&'); ?>{{ recovery={$recoveryString}") }}'>click this link and reset your password!</a> }}
```

but that doesn't work.

How could I write this?

Comment: Use `{!! url(...) !!}` instead of `{{ url(...) }}` not to escape characters.

Comment: Actually that might not do it. You could always separate `echo` statements like this: `<a href="{{ url('forgotpassword/reset') }}?email={{ $user->email }}&recovery={{ $recoveryString }}">click this link and reset your password!</a>`

Comment: That works. Go ahead and post the answer if you want dem' internet points

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
<a href='{{ route("forgetpassword",array( "email@email.com","recoveryString")) }}'>click this link and reset your password!</a>
```

and in your route file

```
Route::get('user/forgetpassword/{email}/{recoveryString}', [
'as' => 'forgetpassword', 'uses' => 'UserController@forgetPassword'
]);
```

you can pass required parameter as array in .blade.php